# Connect .NET Core Web API to MySQL on different docker container

Tags: mysql, .net, docker, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have 2 docker containers running on same virtual machine (Ubuntu server 18.04 on VMWare workstation 12 Player). The first one is MySql Container, which is running on port 3306 and the second one is asp.net core (v2.0) web api (port 5000 on vm and export outside through nginx with port 80 ). My VM api is 192.168.20.197

[project architecture image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDaiu.png)

My connection string on web api project is: `optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("server=localhost;port=3306;database=mydatabase;user=root;CharSet=utf8");`

My docker file content is

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app


COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore


COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out


FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DemoMySql.dll"]
```

I have tried to make a HTTP request to the web api on VM but server response error(500) when i tried to interact with the database (the web api is still work normally when i make it return a sample string such as 192.168.20.197/api/values/samplestring). So How can i connect the web api to mysql on different container ?

p/s: Sorry for my bad grammar

Comment: Can you provide your `docker run` commands and/or your `docker-compose.yml` file? What ever you use to run your containers. You are pointing your connection string to localhost, and in a container the localhost is the container, and not the computer that is running the container.

Comment: i changed my localhost to the vm ip address and it's work :) thks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @Tao Zhou and @Nathan Werry advices, I solved the problem by replacing the localhost in connection string to the ip address of my virtual machine. Then I used docker --link tag (legacy feature of docker) to link the mysql container to the web api container.

```
docker run \
--name <webapi-container-name> \
-p 8082:8081 \
--link <mysql-container-name>:<mysql-image> \
-d <webapi-image>
```

Answer (score 0):

For connecting from `web api` to `mysql`, you could add `Compose` which will create a shared network for `web api` and `mysql`, then you could access `mysql` with `service container name`.

```
version: "3"
  services:
   web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
   db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
     - "8001:5432"
```

You could access `db` by `postgres://db:5432`, refer [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

For another option, you could create your own `Bridge networks` to share the network between two containers. refer [Bridge networks](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/#bridge-networks).

Comment: i have never worked with docker-compose so i use --link to connect web api container to mysql container. I will try the docker-compose later :)